# How can I make my SVG SMIL animation play back correct again?

Tags: svg, svg-animate, smil

I'm a designer with little coding experience and a while ago I played around with SMIL animations and I remember that some browsers did not support specific commands. Now I wanted to review my animations and unfortunately noticed that the browser I originally tested the animations with successfully (opera) also stopped playing my animation back correctly. The blue ball used to move up and down the y-axis and this animation is not working anymore now.

Do you guys know why this animation is not played back correctly anymore in codepen and how I can view the animation as it used to be?

https://codepen.io/clemse/pen/gOYPNJZ

This is the part that does not seem to work:

```
<!-- Animating the ball along the Y Axis, with specific y coordinate values relative to time, with speed dependent on bezier curve -->
<animate
           attributeName="cy"
           begin="0.2s"
           dur="1.6s"
           values="142;10;-5;142;142"
           keySplines="
                       0.1 0.9 1.0 1.0; 
                 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0; 
                       0.5 1.6 0.1 0.9;
                 0.1 0.9 1.0 1.6;" 
           keyTimes="
                       0;0.20;0.40;0.8;1" 
           calcMode="spline"
           repeatCount="indefinite"
           />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at the console and you will see where the problem is. According to the [specs for `keySplines`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/keySplines),

> The values of x1 y1 x2 y2 must all be in the range 0 to 1.

Your example has two values of `1.6`. I have changed them to `0.6` and it works in my browser (Chrome).

```html
<svg style="display:block; margin: 0 auto;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 300 300">

<!-- Background shape--> 
<rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="300" fill="#FCCE01 "/>

<!-- Opening the Group for the Toy-->
<g>
  
<!-- Animating the balls impact on the toyvertically-->  
  <animateTransform
          attributeName="transform"
          type="translate"
          values="0,0;0,8;0,0;0,0;0,0;0,0;0,0;0,0;0,0;0,0;0,0" 
          begin="1.0s" 
          dur="1.6"
          repeatCount="indefinite"
  />
  
<!-- Positioning the toy-->
<g transform="translate(-65,34)">  
  
<!-- Ball shape-->
  <ellipse cx="217" cy="30" rx="15" ry="15"
           fill="#65c8d2"
           stroke="#4e2561" 
           stroke-width="3">

<!-- Animating the ball along the Y Axis, with specific y coordinate values relative to time, with speed dependent on bezier curve -->
    <animate
               attributeName="cy"
               begin="0.2s"
               dur="1.6s"
               values="142;10;-5;142;142"
               keySplines="0.1 0.9 1.0 1.0;1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0;0.5 0.6 0.1 0.9;0.1 0.9 1.0 0.6" 
               keyTimes="0;0.20;0.40;0.8;1" 
               calcMode="spline"
               repeatCount="indefinite"
               />
   
<!-- Animating the balls shape (squashing) along the x axis-->    
    <animate 
               attributeName="rx"
               values="15; 10.5 ; 17 ; 19 ; 15 ; 10.5 ; 17 ; 15 ; 15 ; 15 ; 15"
               begin="0.2s"
               dur="1.6s"
               repeatCount="indefinite"
               />
    
<!-- Closing the object so only the ball gets animated-->
    </ellipse>
  
<!-- Positioning the trigger-->
  <g transform="translate(200,150)"> 

<!-- Drawing the trigger-->
   <path d="M0,0 L-14,0 Q-15,20 3,25 L0,0z "
         style="stroke:#4e2561;
         stroke-width:3;
         fill:#e54e6d">
      
 <!--Animating the triggers rotation-->
      <animateTransform
                        attributeName="transform"
                        type="rotate"
                        values="0 0 0; -30 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0 ; 0 0 0 ; 0 0 0; 0 0 0 ; 0 0 0 ; 0 0 0 ; 0 0 0 "
                        begin="0s"
                        dur="1.6s"
                        fill="freeze" 
                        repeatCount="indefinite"
                        />    
     
    </path>
       
  </g>
  
<!--Positioning the cage-->
<g transform="translate(200,150)">

<!--Drawing the cage-->
  <path d="M0,0 L-18,-52 L52,-52 L34,0 L10,0 L2,-52   M30,-52 L24,0 M-5,-17 L40,-17 M45,-34 L-12,-34"
        style="stroke:#4e2561;
               stroke-width:3;
               fill:none"/>
  </g>
  
<!--Positioning the Cone-->  
  <g transform="translate(200,150)">
   
<!--Drawing the Cone-->      
   <path d="M0,0 L10,75 A1,1 0 0,0 24,75 L34,0 L0,0z "
         style="stroke:#4e2561;
                stroke-width:3;
                fill:#e54e6d"/>
  </g>
    
 </g>
  
</svg>
```